# http web server return zip file in a windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, webserver

hello i'm write a http web server in my app.
I used this code
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/A_simplistic_HTTP_Server_on_Windows_Phone

this procedure works but not have a extentions of file in http response

return a file name without extention (.zip)

```
private async Task<StringBuilder> HandleRequest(StreamSocket socket)
    {

        //Initialize IO classes
        DataReader reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
        reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
        writer.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;

        //handle actual HTTP request
        String request = await StreamReadLine(reader);

        string[] tokens = request.Split(' ');
        if (tokens.Length != 3)
        {
            throw new Exception("invalid http request line");
        }
        string httpMethod = tokens[0].ToUpper();
        string httpUrl = tokens[1];

            //read HTTP headers - contents ignored in this sample
            while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(await StreamReadLine(reader))) ;

            try
            {

                if (httpUrl == "DOWNLOADZIP")
                {
                         using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                         {
                               String content = null;
                               Stream stream;
                               byte[] data;

                               IsolatedStorageFileStream sri = storage.OpenFile("CompressedFiles.zip", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                               if (null != sri)
                               {
                                  stream = sri;
                                  data = new byte[stream.Length];
                                  stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                                  writer.writebytes(data);
                               }
                         }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)//any exception leads to an Internal server error
            {
                writer.WriteString("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal server error\r\n");
                writer.WriteString("Connection: close\r\n");
                writer.WriteString("\r\n");
                writer.WriteString(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        await writer.StoreAsync();//write data actually to the network interface

        socket.Dispose(); 
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a solutions

```
ret.AppendLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
ret.AppendLine("Content-Type: text/html");
ret.AppendLine("Connection: close");
ret.AppendLine("");
ret.AppendLine("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.zip");
```